# How can I initialize QVector<QVector<QString>> *matrix (as class member) with new?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtcore, qvector

I really tried everything but I can't find the solution, I tried first initialize the outer `QVector` then the inner but it wasn't succesful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can't do this, because you missed one `>`. So try this:

```
#include<QDebug>
//...
private:
     QVector<QVector<QString> > *matrix = new QVector<QVector<QString> >;
```

And in constructor:

```
matrix->append(QVector<QString>() << "hello world");
qDebug() << "output: " << *matrix;
```

But I think that you should allocate memory in constructor. For example:

```
private:
     QVector<QVector<QString> > *matrix;
```

In constructor:

```
matrix = new QVector<QVector<QString> >;
matrix->append(QVector<QString>() << "hello world");
qDebug() << "output:" << *matrix;
```

Output in both cases:

> output:  QVector(QVector("hello world") )

Comment: Did you compile that code? Can you really create an object with new in the header? Isn't that what initializer lists are made for?

Comment: @SimonWarta yes it compiles, why not? http://ideone.com/WkkCaV maybe old compilersdon't support this. But anyways I said in my answer that I suggest to allocate memory on constructor(of course we can use initializer list but it is not forbid to allocate memory directly in constructor).

Comment: You're right, it works as long as you are using pointers or copies but not with non-standard constructors: http://ideone.com/mbGOvz

Comment: @SimonWarta: [it is a C++11 feature](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init).

Answer (score 2):

> QVector *matrix (as class member) with new?

There are issues with this, namely:

- You should not allocate a `QVector` on the heap (i.e. as pointers with new).
- You should be utilising `QStringList` more.

What I would personally suggest is this:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QVector>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDebug>

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo() { qDebug() << matrix; }
    private:
        // Could be QStringLiteral, but you could also build it in the
        // constructor if it is dynamic
        QVector<QStringList> matrix{{"foo", "bar", "baz"}, {"hello", "world", "!"}};
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
QVector(("foo", "bar", "baz"), ("hello", "world", "!"))
```

Comment: Could you explain in 1 or 2 sentences, why "You should not allocate a QVector on the heap"? Thx

Comment: @SimonWarta: because it makes the code more complex for not much gain IMHO, especially that QVector is CoW. Thanks.